# Reading / writing new line character from/to xml

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0

I use xml file to store some key/value data:

```
<Resource Key="A1" Value="Some text" />
```

What I am having problems with, is how would I save/load data in Value, if it is a multiline text?

```
<Resource Key="A2" Value="Some text\nin two lines" />
```

which should, when displayed, result in

```
Some text
in two lines
```

If I read above resource using

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load(filePath);

// get all the localized client resource strings
var resource = (from r in document.Descendants("Resource")
                          where r.Attribute("Key").Value == "A2"
                          select r).SingleOrDefault();
```

it will read it with double backslash:

```
Some text\\nin two lines.
```

So, how can I read/save a new line character is some text, that for example, could later be displayed in WPF application or in web application?

**Edit**: here is an example (writes correctly, reads incorrectly):

```
<!-- WPF window xaml code -->
<Grid>
  <Button Name="btn" Content="Click me" />
</Grid>

// WPF window code behind
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    XDocument doc =
          new XDocument(
            new XElement("Resources",
              new XElement("Resource", new XAttribute("Key", "A1"), new XAttribute("Value", @"Some text\nin two lines")))
          );

    const string fileName = @"D:\test.xml";
    doc.Save(fileName);

    doc = XDocument.Load(fileName);

    IDictionary<string, string> keys = (from c in doc.Descendants("Resource")
                                        select c).ToDictionary(c => c.Attribute("Key").Value, c => c.Attribute("Value").Value);

    btn.ToolTip = keys["A1"];
    //btn.ToolTip = "Some text\nin two lines"; // if you uncomment this line, it works as expected
}
```

Comment: Have you tried outputting some xml with a new line to see what it does internally?

Comment: 99% you are looking at the string in the debugger and it shows you escaped `\`. Note that it is unclear what you expect to see there.

Comment: In the debugger, in wpf window, makes no difference. I am going to edit the question so all of you can easily test.

Comment: I just tested your code and it works properly. The double slash is just an escape character shown in debugger.

Comment: On my PC it does not work. Btn tooltip will show a ONE-line tooltip. If you uncomment the last line, it will show TWO-line tooltip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unescaping the string works

```
btn.ToolTip = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape(keys["A1"]);
```

if anyone knows how to avoid escaping while reading from xml (to read it unescaped, as it is), I would be glad to hear about it.